Does Hinduism support astrology, numerology and other stuff like that?
I have seen that Hinduism supports an amalgam of the thoughts of free will and predetermined destiny...
Basically Hinduism says we have a predetermined destiny.. and it is determined by our past karma
Therefore is it possible for any human according to Hinduism to know the future?
It is very confusing that Hinduism supports astrology in the sense that all the Hindu festivals's time and date are calculated astrologically.
But at the same time it is very illogical that wearing a pokhraj ring or golden watch will help mitigate effects of karma which is something that even great seers and sages had to deal with.
Same with numerology; how can a dude mitigate his bad karma by changing his name and stuff..
Please provide an answer if Hinduism supports all of this or not..
[also provide verses from scriptures.. I might need them in case of an argument]

Jyotisa has 2 components - timekeeping [astronomy] & prediction-making [astrology]. Timekeeping is essential in every civilisation & isn't considered unscientific. Prediction-making is the aspect which is hotly debated. And to translate jyotisa as mere astrology is a heavily biased approach. Regarding numerology, it is a completely alien system with no scriptural sanction in Hindu texts. Numerology is more prevalent among the urban people than in rural areas of the country.

So does Hinduism support future-telling?? and other stuff? [my conscience doesn't say so]
